# How to know when VideoView UI elements appear/hide in Android App

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I am currently using a VideoView in an android app to play a video. When the user presses the screen, a simple playback UI appears on the screen automatically (this is rendered automatically/natively by the VideoView). And, when the user is idle for a few seconds, this UI disappears (handled by Android, not my app code)

1. Is there a callback API to know when this UI disappears/fades away?
2. Is there a callback API to know when the VideoView has been pressed?
3. Is there a way to modify the duration for how long these UI components exist on the video before it fades away?
4. What is the API to create the animation/fade affect for the UI? If there is no fade effect, is there an API to create a sliding animation effect?

The reason I ask is because I am planning to create an overlaying transparent gradient with icons over the video. I'd like to bring up these icons when the user presses anywhere on the video and have the icons fade away after a certain amount of time. Ex:

[image]

Comment: What does the documentation have to say about it?

Comment: @Simon It seems the documentation doesn't have an API to show when the UI disappears and fades away